# How to apply multicores when using sapply?

Tags: r

```
R 3.1.2
library(RcppRoll)
```

my data.frame

```
y=
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
2 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
3 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 NA  
4 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

my function:

```
    sapply(y, RcppRoll::roll_mean, n = 3, na.rm = T)
```

I have no problem with and works fine but it is very slow when using my huge data. I wonder how we speed up the performance of `sapply` using multi cores or even using for loop in stead?

@Khashaa Yes I tried and it is faster but I have problem with the output:

output:

```
> 
      [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]   16   17   18
```

this cause problem to the rest of my code so I want to be change as:

```
       V1 V2 V3
[1,]   16 17 18
```

ANy idea on this?

Comment: have a look to the foreach package or use the `laply` function from the plyr package that apply function in parallel using parallel backend provided by foreach

Comment: I'd suggest to implement the loop over the columns in Rcpp. If you then still need parallelization then, you could do it at the C++ level too (e.g., see [RcppParallel](http://rcppcore.github.io/RcppParallel/)).

Comment: @Barry The first step would be reading relevant documentation and tutorials (btw. I would make your data.frame a matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific example, you don't need `sapply`. Just `roll_mean(as.matrix(y), 3, na.rm=T)` will suffice

```
y <- runif(1e7) 
dim(y) <- c(1e3, 1e4)
y <- data.frame(y)
system.time(sapply(y, RcppRoll::roll_mean, n = 3, na.rm = T))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 14.120   0.451  18.960 
system.time(RcppRoll::roll_mean(as.matrix(y), 3, na.rm=T))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.329   0.000   0.329 
# About 60x times faster
```

Only difference from the `sapply` result is the `colnames` which you can change as follows

```
res <- RcppRoll::roll_mean(as.matrix(y), 3, na.rm=T)
colnames(res) <- colnames(y)
res
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8   V9
#[1,] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 16.5
#[2,] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
mclapply(y, roll_mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE, mc.cores=detectCores())
```

Or

```
laply(y, .fun=roll_mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE, .parallel=TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried mclapply but with huge data it failed and says;`the length of vector is not supported`,although it worked fine with `mapply`

Comment: I don't think `mapply` has parallelization, so try `laply` (in the `plyr` package).

Comment: Thanks I am getting this warning:`In setup_parallel() : No parallel backend registered`

Comment: I think you will have to use `registerDoMC` or `registerDoParallel` first. Do a search for setting that up, it's pretty simple. It might be OS specific as well.